# What's best way to format C# in WordPress?

Tags: c#, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

Hey bloggers out there!  I've created Wordpress blog that I am hosting myself, and I'm having the hardest time figuring out the best way to add C# snippets to my blog.  What do you all use?

I'm currently using the "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" plugin, and it works great for the most part - the only problem is that switching back to the Visual Editor removes all of the whitsepace padding.  I've tried wrapping the [sourcecode] tags in <pre>'s, but then the formatter doesn't work correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I've spent about 10 hours trying to come up with a robust solution, and no luck.
Cheers!

Comment: Wow!  Awesome responses - I'll have to try'em out after work today, and I'll let y'all know how it goes :)

Comment: To use C# with WP-Syntax plugin write it as `<PRE lang="csharp">{your code here}</PRE>`. It wasnt clear from the documentation so I had to go into the source code to pick this up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [blog post that I wrote](http://ellisweb.net/2008/08/using-syntaxhighlighter-to-format-code-in-wordpress/) on this exact question, which explains how to use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) and fix TinyMCE so that it doesn't mess up your white space or tags (you can either customize one of the tinymce files in Wordpress, or use a [plugin](http://www.engfers.com/plugins/tinymce-valid-elements/) to do it for you).

Comment: Thanks!  That's solves my problem perfectly.  I've drafted a blog post in your honor, I'll put it up tomorrow :).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the WP-Syntax plugin. To use it, you wrap the code with a pre tag with a language attribute. Consolidates the effort.

Answer (score 1):

If Client-Side (JavaScript) Syntax Highlighting is also an option, I can recommend [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which works quite well. Only a little Code escaping is needed to make it zero-friction for me as an author, as I detailed [in a posting](http://www.stum.de/2008/10/19/escaping-code-for-posting-on-the-website-and-removing-indent/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Live Writer to write post for your blog and use Steve Dunns [live writer plugin](http://stevedunns.googlepages.com/codeformatterforwindowslivewriter).