# Where can one post nicely formatted code combined with LaTeX for mathematical expressions?

Tags: math, blogs, code-formatting

Admittedly not a programming question, but I don't really know where else to ask this...

I'm planning to start a blog to post the stuff I'm working on, which is mostly about Expression Trees & Mathematics. Hopefully this will help me focus on the problem at hand instead of going off every possible tangent that comes up.

I wonder if someone out there knows a good place to host a blog with the two following requirements:

(1) Nice support for code listings (as seen [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/), for example).

(2) Support for complex mathematical expressions, ideally in LaTeX (as seen [here](http://kogler.wordpress.com/2008/03/10/blogging-with-latex-content/), for example).

For a while now I've been looking around for posts/articles combining both nicely formatted code and mathematical expressions, but I haven't found anything.

Thanks a lot!

PS - If there's another Q&A forum where this question would fit better, then please let me know and I'll move it there.

EDIT(1): While carrying out some additional research, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742428/whats-best-way-to-format-c-in-wordpress) related SO question (see also resources therein), which then took me to [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/other_notes/). Leaving the question open for now though in case someone wants to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here:

http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?cat=2
http://fugato.net/2007/01/20/latex-in-wordpress/

about LaTeX on Wordpress, syntax higlighting is easy (hint: google for "syntax highlighting") and you can go on any host with WP.

Good luck.

**Edit:** Okay, about that latex - it seems you need to have administrator rights, so any hosting with friendly administrator or virtual server or server hosting/housing :)

**Edit:** As for syntax highlighting:

PHP SH: http://xtractpro.com/articles/CSharp-Syntax-Highlighter.aspx
JS SH: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/

Comment: Thanks - Sure, I did some research on LaTeX support on WP; this seems great but, at the same time, support for code listing doesn't seem to be that great - Am I right or could you please point me to some WP blog with a decent amount of, say, C# code?

Comment: you can look here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/

Comment: Thanks - I'll check those as soon as I can; it might take a while though as I've never blogged before...

Answer (score 1):

For math expressions in LaTeX syntax checkout [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). It can probably be used with most blog hosting services. You just need to be able to add javascript to the page.